# loop con mensaje final en Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Quisiera que al terminar este `loop` saliera un `msgbox` con la leyenda `finalizado`, adjunto mi código:

```
Sub automatizaciónTotal()
      Range("M4").Select
      
      ' el código de abajo le indica para cuando la celda q se active este vacia, entonces para de imprimir después del ultimo permiso
      Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
      
       Range("D3").Value = ActiveCell.Value
      
      ' la linea de codigo de abajo llama a otra macro q es la de impresion individual, la cual se va a repetir mientras no se cumpla la condicion de celda vacia
       Call IMPRESION
        
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
       
      Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: MsgBox "finalizado"

Answer (score 3):

Al terminar tu bucle (despues de `Loop`) muestra el mensaje de esta forma:

```
Sub automatizaciónTotal()
      Range("M4").Select
      
      ' el código de abajo le indica para cuando la celda q se active este vacia, entonces para de imprimir después del ultimo permiso
      Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
      
       Range("D3").Value = ActiveCell.Value
      
      ' la linea de codigo de abajo llama a otra macro q es la de impresion individual, la cual se va a repetir mientras no se cumpla la condicion de celda vacia
       Call IMPRESION
        
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
       
      Loop

      MsgBox "finalizado"  

End Sub
```